# Creating favourites/bookmark list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm currently trying to create a favourites/bookmark list on my website, the aim of this list is that a user can double click on a link or click a icon to set the link as a favourite. The problem I'm having is that the link can be appended twice to the list. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm saving the linkID and linkContent in a object to a file, then reading the file. Also the link can be appended twice in the file. How do I stop duplicates being saved in the file?

**Code below:**

```js
function SaveToFavouriteLinkFile(linkID, linkContent) {

  var saveFavouriteLinkObject = {};
  saveFavouriteLinkObject.linkID = linkID;
  saveFavouriteLinkObject.linkContent = linkContent;
  // Writing
  $.ajax({
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({
      action: 'write',
      content: saveFavouriteLinkObject
    }),
    url: 'php/saveFavouriteLinks.php',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
}


$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
  switch (e.target.innerText) {
    case " Server":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='serverBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> Server <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("serverBTNFav", "Server");

      break;

    case " Group":
      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='groupBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> Group <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("groupBTNFav", "Group");

      break;

    case " User":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='userBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> User <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("userBTNFav", "User");

      break;

    case " Sync":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='syncBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> Sync <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("syncBTNFav", "Sync");

      break;

    case " Patient Listing":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='PatientListBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> Patient Listing <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("PatientListBTNFav", "Patient Listing");

      break;

    case " App Settings":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='AppSettingsBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> App Settings <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("AppSettingsBTNFav", "App Settings");

      break;

    case " Logging":

      $("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id='LoggingBTNFav' class='selectNavigationBTN'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTN'></i> Logging <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star pull-right'></i></a></li>");
      SaveToFavouriteLinkFile("LoggingBTNFav", "Logging");

      break;
  }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```js
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
      case 'write':

        // New favourites item for list
        $favouriteLink = $_REQUEST['content']['linkContent'];
        // New favourites item ID
        $favouriteLinkID = $_REQUEST['content']['linkID'];
        // File for item to be stored
        $file = "favouriteLinks.txt";

        // Existing items in favourites list
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);


        $result = getArrayIndex($json, $favouriteLink);

        if (empty($result)) {
          echo json_encode("I did not find your string: ".$favouriteLink);
        } else {
          echo json_encode("The index of your main array, where  '".$favouriteLink.
            "' found is: ".$result);
        }

        foreach ($json as $obj) {
      if ($obj['favouriteLinkContent'] == $favouriteLink)
      {
       echo json_encode("HELLO");
       break;
      }
                else
                {
                
        $json[] = array("favouriteLinkContent" => $favouriteLink, "favouriteLinkID" => $favouriteLinkID);
     file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
                }
   }


        break;

      case 'read':

        $data = file_get_contents('favouriteLinks.txt');
        echo $data;

        break;
    }
```

Comment: in your saveFavouriteLinks.php make sure you check if it doesn't already exist, this is a backend issue, not jquery/javascript, there is a problem in your php code

Comment: @JeremyC. I've added my PHP code to my question, could you take alook at it?

Comment: this isn't the code that is saving your new favorite, this is where you read them

Comment: @JeremyC. I've got both in the same file, they're split by "case: write" and "case: read"

Comment: well in any way if you know where it's being written then it's fine: do this: before you write your new favorite, check your favorites file to see if it already has that url or not

Comment: @JeremyC. I've updated my code, this is what i've got to write it

Comment: before I read through the rest of this, here's a pointer: if you do comparison in php try using tripple comparator instead of double (it's best practice when comparing objects of same type) so instead of $obj['favouriteLinkContent'] == $favouriteLink do $obj['favouriteLinkContent'] === $favouriteLink

Comment: @JeremyC. Thanks for this pointer, i'll sure to remember this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$linkexists = false;    
foreach ($json as $obj) {
   if ($obj['favouriteLinkContent'] == $favouriteLink) {
    echo json_encode("HELLO");
    $linkexists = true;
   }

}

if(!$linkexists){
   $json[] = array("favouriteLinkContent" => $favouriteLink,
                   "favouriteLinkID" => $favouriteLinkID);
   file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
}
```

As it was you were inserting every time you ran into an $obj that didn't have the same linkcontents (so if the first couple of $obj objects had a different one you would insert the same favorite obj until you ran into one that had the same content)