# 'Add to Reading List' from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, safari, microsoft-edge

Browsers like Safari and Edge have the option to save things as bookmarks, but also to save pages for later viewing on a reading list, where in some cases they are available offline.

It is relatively easy to create a button on a web page that will add an link to a users bookmarks when pressed (see [Creating favourites/bookmark list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573543/creating-favourites-bookmark-list)), but is there a way to add a link to a reading list from a link on that page?

Is it possible to create a link on a webpage, that, when pressed, adds a link to the reading list?

Comment: Javascript in a page doesn't have access to many higher level browser features. What you are asking for would be wide open for abuse. If browser itself doesn't make it available using right click context menu you are probably out of luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this. You can prompt your readers to read your articles later, but they have to do this on their own. If you want a one-click button for adding a web page to a reading list you can look at publisher solutions from [Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com/publishers) and [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/publisher/button).

You can, however, switch the page to reading mode with a link. Safari uses `safari-reader://example.com/document` and Edge uses `read:https://example.com/document`. Other browsers use [other URIs](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/browser-reading-view-uri) as there [aren’t any standards for reading mode](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/browser-reading-mode-parsers).